# How to use a temp table to manipulate data before pasting to Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row, copy-paste

I have a VBA script that copies and pastes data from a "Source" sheet to a "Working Area" sheet. The VBA evaluates if certain data is present and makes adjustments to the layout so it will match the layout in the "Working Area" tab.

---

**ISSUE:** An insert command adds a row of cells (Column A - X only) to get the column headers from the source sheet to line up with the column headers on the Working area sheet.
Unfortunately, this changes the target cells for all formulas on the worksheet. (ie formulas on row 21 now pull from cells in row 22). That's bad.

---

**Overarching question:**  Can the VBA do all this manipulation in a temp table, when complete, THEN paste to the "working area" so no manipulation is completed in the "Working Area" tab?... or some other quick fix?

---

**Current Code:** I tried to get around this formula issue by doing the row insert in the SOURCE tab. This works...but it is manipulating the SOURCE, which I don't want to do. I want to keep that static.

---

**Additional Background:**
The "SOURCE" is a report that is dynamic. It only includes rows and columns if data is present. This cannot be changed.  This is a problem because the "Working Area" tab contains all possible fields and has numerous equations that run on each row. *In short if "Deductions" are missing, I have to add a deductions row and then shift columns of data into the correct columns*

---

**Current code:**

```
Sub Copy_And_Move_Columns_From_Pay_Reg_Source_to_Pay_Reg_Working_Area()
    '
    Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("A:X").ClearContents
    Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("A:X").ClearFormats
    
    If Sheets("WD Pay Reg Source").Range("a14") = "Deductions" Then
        Sheets("WD Pay Reg Source").Range("A:X").Copy Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("A:X")
    Else
        Sheets("WD Pay Reg Source").Range("A14:X14").Insert
        Sheets("WD Pay Reg Source").Range("A:R").Copy Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("A:R")
        Sheets("WD Pay Reg Source").Range("S:V").Copy Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("U:X")
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S19").Value = "Deductions"
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S20").Value = "Name"
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("T20").Value = "Value"
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S19:T20").Font.Color = vbRed
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S1").Value = "MAKE SURE Row 20 is the header row!!"
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S1").Font.Color = vbRed
        Sheets("Pay reg working area").Range("S1").Font.Size = 24
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Creating a copy of the report sheet would simplify this.

    `Sheets("Pay reg working area").Copy before:=Sheets(1)
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    ' manipulate data and copy to "Pay reg working area"
    sht.Delete`